# Getting around stop error/missing driver for XP boot off BootDisk

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot, bios, bsod

I have a workstation attached to a very expensive machine (cost>$150k) where the manufacturer of said machine stopped offering support.  The machine itself seems fine but I have been unable to boot WinXP from disk or Ghost.

The error is the classic 0x0000007B, and here are the full parameters (does anyone know where you can get parameter specific information, I've never found that):

`0x0000007B (0xF78D663C, 0xC0000034, blank, blank)`

I thought that as the machine went down that this would be a good time to upgrade to Win7, but I was unable to get the MIDI control drivers from XP to function in 7.  I was able to install 32 and 64 bit version of Win7 and Debian, without issue.  Similarly, all the checks I've done of the disk, memory and MOBO have checked out ok (using hiren's boot disk).  Again the machine is no longer supported, thus a driver update seems out of the question.  I assume however that since we running into a '7B error that the problem is with one of the drivers for a HD, not a PCI card.

The machine is a modified [Fujitsu Siemens Celsius R650](http://globalsp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/ds-celsius-R650.pdf) with 4 HDs, one of which was a dedicated Ghost drive (Norton back up drive).  I of course can't get the recovery to work because I can't get it to boot of installation disks, including Norton's.  This leads me to a conclusion that XP doesn't have one of the drivers needed that later versions and OS seem to be able to use?  Further, it seems like I'm going to have to find a 3.5" floppy to put said drivers on, after I figure out which one is failing, and load it on there (probably from Win7 because it's the only machine we have that still has a 3.5" floppy drive).

So my distilled questions are:

1. Can anyone get me more specific information on the parameters?  I've already Googled around and found plenty of the information I knew applied to the common '7B stop error, but I'm curious on the information provided by the parameters.
2. Is there a good way to figure out which driver is causing the problem (assuming that is the problem), if I have multiple drives in.  As all the others are marked as slaves, I would assume the main OS would be the only one that could cause a stop error, but I think it should be a supported drive.
3. Is there a way to use anything other than 3.5" floppy to provide the driver if needed?  I really have no idea where I'm going to find one.

Comment: 0xC0000034 = AHCI driver missing. Looks like you changed the SATA mode from IDE to AHCI before installing Win7. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314082/en-us

Comment: That occurred to me as well.  On the BIOS I tried changing the SATA mode to "LEGACY" which I thought would force IDE?

Comment: what was the old mode before installing Win7?